# USDA PS&D API query not filtering correctly

Tags: r

I'm new to API programming so this question might have an obvious answer, but thanks for hanging in there with me.

I'm  trying to use the `USDA FAS' PS&D API` ([documentation here](https://apps.fas.usda.gov/psdonline/app/index.html#/app/about)) to get grain balance sheet attributes (`production`, `consumption`, `exports`, etc.) for selected countries (`Argentina`, `Brazil`, etc.).

While I can get the API to send me data for all countries for a specific crop/year, I cannot find a way to:

1. get the response to send back ONLY data for Argentina and Brazil, or
2. specify multiple years of data to be returned.

I've tried specifying various country names/codes as query parameters but the resulting data still has all the countries.

Here is my existing code, which works to return return corn data for ALL countries for the 2018 year.

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

## This is a fake API Key 
msKEY = "ABDC-123456-HGFRE-58AB"

baseURL <- "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/PSDOnlineDataServices/api/CommodityData/GetCommodityDataByYear?"

x <- GET(baseURL, query = list(
  CommodityCode = "0440000",
  marketYear = 2018,
  country = "BZ",
  ),
  add_headers(API_KEY = msKEY)
)

status_code(x)

x2 <- fromJSON(
  content(
    x, as = "text"
  )
)
str(x2)
```

I expect this code to return corn data for 2018 for `Brazil` only, but it returns data for all countries. There are no error codes thrown (that I'm aware of) and I'm thoroughly stumped.

Any thoughts/suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little too late, but the code is referring to BRAZIL as BZ when the code is BR. Also there is an extra term in the query list after de country code that should be eliminated.

```
x <- GET(baseURL, query = list(
  CommodityCode = "0440000",
  marketYear = 2018,
  country = "BR"),
add_headers(API_KEY = msKEY)
)

status_code(x)

x2 <- fromJSON(
  content(
    x, as = "text"
  )
)
str(x2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Good catch on the "BR" vs. "BZ" issue as well as the extra (missing) element in the query string. When you ran the code with "BR" as the country identifier, did the API filter and return only data for Brazil? I copy/pasted your code and the API still returned data for every country, not just Brazil. I've even tried several iterations of using the country code (BR) and the full name in the query and it doesn't seem to make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay. You're right on the issue with the country identifier. The filter in the query does not work. I also realized they have two different endpoints for the same data, which affects the query and results. I wrote the following code to get the most out of it and then filter the country in the resulting dataframe:

```
products <- c("Meal, Soybean", 
              "Meal, Soybean (Local)")

selected_products <- product_codes %>% 
  filter(product_codes$CommodityName %in% products)
  
market_years <- c(1980:2022)

# for loop - complete

df <- list()
df_y <- list()

for (i in 1:length(selected_products$CommodityCode)) {
  
  for (j in 1:length(market_years)) {
    
    baseURL <- "https://apps.fas.usda.gov/PSDOnlineDataServices/api/CommodityData/GetCommodityDataByYear?"
    
    m <- GET(baseURL, 
             query = list(CommodityCode = selected_products$CommodityCode[i],
                          marketYear = market_years[j]),
             add_headers(API_KEY = msKEY))
    
    m2 <- fromJSON(content(m, as = "text"))
    
    df_y[[j]] <- m2
    
  }
  
  df[[i]] <- df_y
  
}

  mega_df <- df %>% 
  bind_rows()
```